# Resize the images after uploading!

Tags: php, html, upload, imagick

html form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" /><p /><input type="submit" value="Uplaod" />
</form>
```

php function

```
function createResizedIMK($img, $imgPath, $thumbDir, $suffix, $by) {
  // add in the suffix after the '.' dot.
    $newNameE = explode(".", $img);
    $newName = ''. $newNameE[0] .''. $suffix .'.'. $newNameE[1] .'';

  // ImageMagicK doesnt like '/' and 'x' characters in the command line call.
  // And workout the size based on '$by'.
    $uploadedImg = ''. $imgPath .'/'. $img .'';
    $newResized = ''. $reduceDir .'/'. $newName .'';
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("$imgPath/$img");
    $newWidth = ($width/$by);
    $newHeight = ($height/$by);
    $newRes = ''. $newWidth .'x'. $newHeight .'';

  // This makes a command line call to ImageMagicK.
  // My path to ImageMagicK Convert is '/usr/lib/php/bin/convert'
  // 'convert' is a program (UNIX) so no forward slash.
    $cr = system("/usr/lib/php/bin/convert -resize $newRes $uploadedImg $newResized", $retval);

    return $cr;
}
```

upload.php

```
$imgDir  ="uploads";
$resDir  ="resized";
$thumbDir="thumbs";

$img     = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmpPath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if (move_uploaded_file($tmpPath,"$imgDir/$img"))
{
$resize = createResizedIMK($img, $imgDir, $resDir, "resized-", 2);
$thumb  = createThumbIMK($img, $imgDir, $thumbDir, "thumb-", 150, 150);
}
```

this will create three images "the original,resized one and the thumbnail",

- /uploads/$img
- /resized/$img
- /thumbs/$img

How can I make this to create just two images (resized one and the thumbnail) with out the original image!

- /resized/$img
- /thumbs/$img

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the uploaded file right after the creation of the resized and thumb file with

```
unlink($imgDir .'/'. $img);
```

right after

```
$thumb  = createThumbIMK($img, $imgDir, $thumbDir, "thumb-", 150, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlink the original one

```
if (move_uploaded_file($tmpPath,"$imgDir/$img"))
{
$resize = createResizedIMK($img, $imgDir, $resDir, "resized-", 2);
$thumb  = createThumbIMK($img, $imgDir, $thumbDir, "thumb-", 150, 150);
unlink($imgDir.'/'.$img);
}
```